# fold inverts the order of a sequence

Tags: arrays, f#

The order of my Sequence, array etc matters.  I have tried converting between List, Seq and Array to see if there are differences and in each case it inverses the order.

I have a seq of [noun] [verb] [ajective] for example, which is transformed into strings and then folded together.  A sample response given this template might be *"bad run bandits"* instead of *"bandits run bad".*

Any thoughts on why fold does this or how to get it to execute in the appropriate order?

```
let res = template |> Seq.map(fun pos -> 
                    let e = s |> PredictionEngine.GetRandom
                    pos |> PredictionEngine.GetBestPartOfSpeechWord e)
                    |> Seq.fold(fun acc w -> w.Text + " " + acc) ""
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this is just a matter of changing the order of your last function to:

```
Seq.fold(fun acc w -> acc + " " + w.Text) ""
```

Like this the new itens get concatenated to the end of the old ones. A minimum example of this working can be seen in the following snippet:

```
["Bandits";"Run";"Bad"]
|> Seq.fold(fun acc w -> acc + " " + w) ""
|> printfn "%s"
```

Comment: Its always something simple.  This is totally right!

Answer (score 3):

If you have such common job as concatenating strings I recommend using functions from library.

```
["noun"; "verb"; "adj"]
|> String.concat " "
```

On daily basis work, I think, there are not so many problems that require writing custom folding.

Comment: I used fold to do a map + concat in one shot.  not sure on performance difference though